# Vue3 - Uncaught TypeError: n2 is not a function - emit

Tags: vue.js, onclick, event-handling, vuejs3, emit

I want to emit an event from the footer (in App.vue with router-view) to a component inside the router-view.

In the footer

```
 <div
  v-for="(timeInterval, index) in store.timeIntervals"
  :key="timeInterval.id"
  @click="setTimeInterval(timeInterval.id)"
>
  <img
    :src="timeIntervalImages[index]"
    class="w-8 h-8 mr-4"
    :class="timeInterval.id == selectedTimeIntervalId ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-50'"
  />
</div>
```

This is the function that is called when click a button on footer:

```
methods: {
     setTimeInterval: function (timeIntervalId: number) {
       this.store.storeSelectedTimeInterval(timeIntervalId);
       this.selectedTimeIntervalId = timeIntervalId;
       this.emitter.emit('refreshUnits');
     },
}
```

This is inside the component that needs to run function:

```
 mounted() {
   this.emitter.on('refreshUnits', this.loadUnits());
 },
```

But I get an error and a warning:

[image]

I tried both @click and @click.prevent. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try converting this `setTimeInterval: function (timeIntervalId: number) {` into an arrow function or a named function: `setTimeInterval (timeIntervalId: number) {` or `setTimeInterval: (timeIntervalId: number) => {` you must be having a scope issue also it could better to share a bigger portion of your code.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. I will update the question and add more code.

Comment: You also may need to apply binding here : `this.emitter.on('refreshUnits', this.loadUnits());` -> this.emitter.on('refreshUnits', this.loadUnits.bind(this));